# Not Able To Access From Other Computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, http

I have a website in my system. I am able to access but other systems which are there in my LAN  not able to access that website. p.s. They are able to access my shared folders. I think problem with only using http. Anybody please help? We are using windows 7

Comment: Please provide with more details on your configurations so that the others were able to help you. As it currently stands, your question makes people guessing, and this doesn't seem to be very constructive.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to [enable HTTP in your firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Allow-a-program-to-communicate-through-Windows-Firewall).

Do this by going to Control Panel » Windows Firewall » Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall.

[image]

Comment: please add an image with English.

Comment: I haven't got an english system, sorry ...

Comment: @bummi Next time please try to search for the English menu options, otherwise your answer really won't be that helpful. I added a link to official documentation, for example.